# Why does $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n^2 - n }{2}$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

In a proof in *Introduction to Algorithms,* the book says $\binom{n}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{2}}  = \frac{n^2 - n }{2}\cdot \frac{1}{n^{2}}$, which implies $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n^2 - n }{2}$.

Why are these equivalent? Is it a special case of a more general rule?

Comment: ... just look up the definition.

Comment: I have seen binomial coefficients defined combinatorially, recursively and algebraically (as the coefficients in binomial exponentiation). I have also seen them defined by the formulas. The proof depends  on how they are defined.

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k: then you weren't thinking. You just plug in $n$ and $k=2$ to that formula and simplify.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I suppose you're right.

Comment: @symplectomorphic That seems like an unnecessarily aggressive tone to take, but I think OP understands the problem now at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it a special case of a more general rule?

**Yes.** In general, we have that 
$$
\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
$$
whenever $k\leq n$ and $0$ if $k>n$. You can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations) for a more intuitive description of this using a combinatorial argument. In your case, you have $k=2$ (so you truly do have a "special case" of a more general rule). Thus, we have the following;
$$\require{cancel}
\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!}=\frac{n(n-1)\cancel{(n-2)!}}{2!\cancel{(n-2)!}}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{n^2-n}{2},
$$
which is what you wanted to show. Does that clear things up?

Answer (score 4):

$\binom{n}{2}$ is the number of subsets of size $2$ from a set of size $n$. There are $n$ ways to choose the first element, and $n-1$ ways to choose the secon element. but sets are not "ordered", so we must divide by two and we have $\frac{n\cdot(n-1)}{2}$ such subsets. Thus $\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{n^2-n}{2}$.+

---

Alternatively use induction:

Base:
$\binom{2}{2}=1=\frac{2^2-2}{2}$

Induction:

$\binom{n}{2}=\binom{n-1}{2}+\binom{n-1}{n}$ by pascal recurrence.

$\binom{n-1}{2}+\binom{n-1}{2}=\frac{(n-1)^2-(n-1)}{2}+(n-1)$ by induction.

$\frac{(n-1)^2-(n-1)}{2}+(n-1)=\frac{(n-1)^2-(n-1)+2(n-1)}{2}=\frac{(n-1)^2+(n-1)}{2}=\frac{n^2-2n+1+n-1}{2}=\frac{n^2-n}{2}$